# Вставить адрес в input при нажатии на кнопку определить. Яндекс Карты

Tags: javascript, jquery, yandex-maps-api, input

Есть код в котором при нажатии на карту указывается адрес и вписывает его в input с id **address**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    ymaps.ready(init);
    function init() {
        var  myInput = document.getElementById("address"),
            myPlacemark,
            myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
                center: [55.862267, 48.372041],
                zoom: 13
            }, {
                searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
            });

 // Слушаем клик на карте.
        myMap.events.add('click', function (e) {
            var coords = e.get('coords');

            // Если метка уже создана – просто передвигаем ее.
            if (myPlacemark) {
                myPlacemark.geometry.setCoordinates(coords);
            }
            // Если нет – создаем.
            else {
                myPlacemark = createPlacemark(coords);
                myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
                // Слушаем событие окончания перетаскивания на метке.
                myPlacemark.events.add('dragend', function () {
                    getAddress(myPlacemark.geometry.getCoordinates());
                });
            }
            getAddress(coords);
        });

 // Создание метки.
        function createPlacemark(coords) {
            return new ymaps.Placemark(coords, {
                iconCaption: 'поиск...'
            }, {
                preset: 'islands#violetDotIconWithCaption',
                draggable: true
            });
        }

 // Определяем адрес по координатам (обратное геокодирование).
        function getAddress(coords) {
            myPlacemark.properties.set('iconCaption', 'поиск...');
            ymaps.geocode(coords).then(function (res) {
                var firstGeoObject = res.geoObjects.get(0),
                    address = firstGeoObject.getAddressLine();

                myPlacemark.properties
                    .set({
                        // Формируем строку с данными об объекте.
                        iconCaption: [
                            // Название населенного пункта или вышестоящее административно-территориальное образование.
                            firstGeoObject.getLocalities().length ? firstGeoObject.getLocalities() : firstGeoObject.getAdministrativeAreas(),
                            // Получаем путь до топонима, если метод вернул null, запрашиваем наименование здания.
                            firstGeoObject.getThoroughfare() || firstGeoObject.getPremise()
                        ].filter(Boolean).join(', '),
                        // В качестве контента балуна задаем строку с адресом объекта.
                        balloonContent: address
                    });
                myInput.value = address;
                localStorage.setItem('value', address); // При вызове функции (которая срабатываем при нажатии на карте) записываем данные в localstorage
            });
        }
        if(localStorage.getItem('value')){ // При выполнении функции init, если есть данные в localstorage, то...
            myInput.value = localStorage.getItem('value'); // Вставляем значение в input
        }
    }
});
```

Как сделать функцию, которая при нажатии на кнопку "Определить местоположение" вставляла полученный адрес  в input **address** автоматически ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно получить доступ к элементу управления geolocationControl и прослушивая определение положения пользователя добавить вызов функции геокодера и изменения input'а:

```
var geoButton = myMap.controls.get('geolocationControl');
geoButton.events.add('locationchange', function (event) {
    var coords = event.get('position');
    myMap.panTo(coords);
    getAddress(coords);
});
```